# How to remove this empty <p><span>&nbsp;</span></p> tag using regular expression and php

Tags: php, regex

I have a requirement that i need to remove this from a piece of text.

```
<p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
```

for example

```
<p><span>Because the coffee grinds stay in the pod there is virtually no cleaning either.</span></p>
<p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span>Hey presto, your coffee, your way every time. </span></p>.
```

I have tried to to remove empty

```
<p></p>
```

using regular expression

```
$pattern1 = "/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/";
```

How should i modify this to remove the empty tag

```
<p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just remove the string `<p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>`?

Comment: Hi yes i have removed with str_replace.yaa i didn't thought about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to remove this piece of code, you don't need regex at all. Just do a simple replace, using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$string = str_replace("<p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>", "", $string);
```

Comment: @user993516 Don't forget to accept answers that worked for you by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer